# How to ignore nil json values in codable

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I currently getting receipts back both `Auto-Renewable` and `Non-Renewable`. But the `Non-Renewable` doesn't come back with `expires_date` json key. How can I ignore this. I'm trying to avoid making `expires_date` an optional. When I make it optional Apple sends a response back. Is there way I can decode the json without making `expires_date` optional.

```
struct Receipt: Codable {

    let expiresDate: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case expiresDate = "expires_date"
    }
}
```

Right now I can currently get

> > "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"expires_date\", intValue: nil) (\"expires_date\")."

Comment: `without making expires_date optional` so what you expect as the value of that field, in case JSON contains nil ?

Comment: `Auto_renewable` receipts contain `expires_date` while `Non Renewable` don't. There Apple checks all the json and refuses to send a response. when I make It optional it works for `Auto_renewable` but crashes for `Non Renewable`. Since I'm using `SwiftStoreKit` for the `Non-Renewable` it checks both receipts and crashes saying `expires_date ` is nil.

Comment: @Dharmesh that's what I don't wanna do and trying to avoid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to implement your own `init(from: Decoder)` and use `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` before nil coalescing to a default value.

```
struct Receipt: Codable {
    let expiresDate: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case expiresDate = "expires_date"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)        
        self.expiresDate = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .expiresDate)
            ?? "1970" //Default value
    }        
}
```

NOTE:

- If `Receipt` has more key-value pairs, then you would have to manually decode those as well.

---

#### Usage Example:

```
let data = """
[{
  "expires_date": "2019"
},
{

}]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode([Receipt].self, from: data)
    print(obj)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about manual decode it:

```
struct Receipt: Codable {

    let expiresDate: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case expiresDate = "expires_date"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let expDate = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .expiresDate) {
            self.expiresDate = expDate
        } else {
            self.expiresDate = "sth"
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct Receipt: Codable {

    let expiresDate: String
    let b: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case expiresDate = "expires_date"
        case b = "b"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let expDate = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .expiresDate) {
            self.expiresDate = expDate
        } else {
            self.expiresDate = "sth"
        }
        b = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .b)
    }
}


let a = """
{
    "b": "asdf"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(Receipt.self, from: a)
print(myStruct) //Receipt(expiresDate: "sth", b: "asdf")
```

Comment: I tired this before and it crashes my non renewable saying expiryDate is nil

Comment: Hmm? Why it's nil? I set it to "sth" if the key "expires_date" cannot be parse, try this again and it should work, make sure all other key are correct though